# How to get autofill formula to skip a row at a time and use correct formula?

Tags: excel, offset

I am using an IF function to fill the every other cell in a row. However, the function wont drag down to be applied to all cells in the column. I have attached a picture to hopefully explain better. IF cells in column E are filled, i would like the contents of that cell appear in column I, however i would like to skip a row then display the next cell.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0v7IW.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Simple method: enter zzA1 in C1 and zzA2 in C3. Select C1:C4, and drag the fill handle down as far as needed. Then replace (Ctrl+H) `zz` with `=`. Job done. :)

Comment: Thanks, helped a lot

Comment: I am now trying to do the same, but with an IF formula. When i try to use the same method as before it does not work. I get the same problem as original, any idea?

Comment: You'll need to use something like `INDEX(A:A,(row()-1)*2+1)` to get every other row in column A.

Comment: Sorry, i dont quite understand how i would do that. ```````` zz(If(E17="","-",E17))```````` above is my formula so far

Comment: Forget the `zz` stuff for this, as it won't work here. Which row is that formula in?

Comment: Ive edited the question to hopefully provide a more detailed question, and help understanding of question

Comment: There aren't any row numbers visible, so it doesn't help I'm afraid. The formula will need to make an adjustment based on the row it's in and the row it's looking at.

Comment: Sorry, I have changed the image now to show the rows, cells and columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've got the project names to the left of the formula cells, you can use those:

```
=INDEX(E$16:E$26,match(G14,$A$16:$A$26,0))
```